# How to do multiline Jinja2 conditionals in single block?

Tags: ansible, template, jinja

The below code is rejected as syntactically incorrect:

```
{%
    if inventory_hostname in groups.aptcache
        set cachehost = 'localhost'
    else
        set cachehost = groups['aptcache'] | first
    endif
%}
cache={{ cachehost }}
```

I hope, my intent is clear enough for a Jinja2 guru to correct me... Please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't put the if-then-else in one block unless it is an if-expression. Either:

```
{% if inventory_hostname in groups.aptcache %}
{%      set cachehost = 'localhost' %}
{% else %}
{%      set cachehost = groups['aptcache'] | first %}
{% endif %}
cache={{ cachehost }}
```

or

```
cache={{ 'localhost' if inventory_hostname in groups.aptcache else groups['aptcache'] | first }}
```

Comment: I know, I can -- but that seems ugly -- is there really no way to keep it in a _single_ {% ... %} block spanning multiple lines?